# what's the best way to retrieve the timezone using firemonkey on delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a project on firemonkey which runs on android, windows, ios.
I need to retrieve the timezone where the device is located at the moment of my request.
What I need is something like Europe/Rome, Europe/London not the description or the hours difference.

I'm using delphi 11 with all the updates.

Thank you

Comment: Check out the `TTimeZone` class in the `System.DateUtils` unit. It contains a `TTimeZone.local.GetDisplayName` function. It's not exactly the directly what you want but as far as I know it's the best that you will get without any third party libraries. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils.TTimeZone.GetDisplayName

Comment: Hello, thank you. However this does not help me much. It returns me "ora legale Europa occidentale" which is far from what I need. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to build a manifest with all the continents linked to their time zones. Eg: GMT+2 = Europe, Asia and Africa. You get can get a list of time zones from googling along with the regions.